# OpenSSL missing during ./configure. How to fix?

Tags: linux, openssl

I was trying to install node.js and found OpenSSL support missing during `./configure`.

How can I fix it? Is it a mandatory step? Would the `--without-ssl` option fix the problem?

```
# ./configure

Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : not found
Checking for openssl                     : not found
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : not found
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : not found
/home/ec2-user/node-v0.6.6/wscript:374: error: Could not autodetect OpenSSL 
                                               support.

Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. Use configure --without-ssl 
to disable this message.
```

Comment: For me in my Debian 9 (ubuntu) : apt update && apt install -y openssl && apt install -y libc6 && apt install -y libssl1.1 && apt install -y ca-certificates and then ./configure

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Yes, it's a mandatory step. You cannot remove OpenSSL from a program uses it, the same way you couldn't remove random engine parts from a car.

The OpenSSL library is usually already installed, but you have to install the header files. Depending on your Linux distribution, you'll need these packages:

- Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS - `openssl-devel`
- Debian, Ubuntu - `libssl-dev`
- Arch - `openssl`

---

<sub>Technically one could *replace* OpenSSL with, say, NSS, but that's not the point here.</sub>

Comment: thanks a lot, i installed header by yum install openssl-devel

Comment: Ah makes sense now. This is needed for wget to ./configure with ssl as well.

Comment: After using [grawitys answer](https://superuser.com/a/371912/743888) while trying to configure squid (3.5.26) with openssl I've stumbled onto some weird side effect: Unless you have "pkg-config" installed, the library "openssl" and "libssl-dev" gets treated as if it was missing. So I had to install pkg-config as well. It is used in the configure script (around line 23362) to find the path and existence of this package. On debian it is installed by: > `apt-get install pkg-config`

Comment: @MihovilBubnjar got an error "configure: error: library 'ssl' is required for OpenSSL" when tried to build squid with ssl, install pkg-config fixed this error

Answer (score 12):

debian:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev

apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: How and why does this help fix the problem?

Comment: @KevinPanko `libssl-dev`

Comment: @KevinPanko this works I can confirm. Albert's answer is correct.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I did not doubt it, but it helps when an answer explains why a command is needed.

Comment: this didn't solved for me, also configure --without-ssl gave me that it is a required package

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't.

You can still compile nodejs with `./configure --without-ssl`

Answer (score 2):

This is showing up on Google for a problem that may come up with some installations - possibly links-g.  I had the problem on Archlinux with links-utf8 and links-g-directfb.

Likely presentation:

```
checking OPENSSL_CFLAGS... 
checking OPENSSL_LIBS... -lssl -lcrypto 
checking for OpenSSL... no
configure: error: OpenSSL not found
```

Try this:

```
sed -i "/ac_cpp=/s/\$CPPFLAGS/\$CPPFLAGS -O2/" configure
```

Using this command before your `./configure` step should fix it.

Comment: why is that patch fixing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You must install `openssl-devel` in your OS with:

`yum install openssl-devel.x86_64`

`./configure --with-tls`

`make install`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't succeed with **libssl-dev** only, over *Debian* distro, you could include **both SSL Library** versions same time

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libssl1.0
```