# OpenSSL missing during ./configure. How to fix? my system is macos

Tags: linux

```
checking for PCRE library ... found  
checking for PCRE JIT support ... found  
checking for OpenSSL library ... not found   
checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/local/ ... not found       
checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found   
checking for OpenSSL library in /opt/local/ ... not found  
./configure: error: SSL modules require the OpenSSL library.You can either do not enable the modules, or install the OpenSSL libraryinto the system, or build the OpenSSL library statically from the sourcewith nginx by using --with-openssl=<path> option.ERROR: failed to run command: sh ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openresty/nginx \...
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [OpenSSL missing during ./configure. How to fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/371901/openssl-missing-during-configure-how-to-fix)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL missing during ./configure. How to fix?](https://superuser.com/questions/371901/openssl-missing-during-configure-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Download and compile OpenSSL:

```
cd /usr/local/src
curl --remote-name https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz
tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1d
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl/
make
make install
```

Verify:

```
openssl version -a
```

This should get you started to compile OpenSSL yourself. Afterwards, configure should find the installation and use it.

Comment: i try it but the mistake is still there.

Comment: @gangwang - The error message you received has two solutions.  Have you tried both of those solutions? Edit your question, please do not submit a comment in response to this question, your question is severally lacking in the required details to answer your question.

Comment: @gangwang - Please take this comment to heart.  I literally indicated you should not reply to my comment with a comment, but clarify your question by editing, but you submitted a comment and made no improvement to your question.  If you have any additional clarification, please do not submit a comment, instead edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry,i am a rookie,,the account was created today,the still question is,i wanna to use kong, this is a gateway plateform,i follow the steps of this article step by step,but when i install the openresty , the question appear，the article link:https://blog.csdn.net/lyking2001/article/details/82799068

Comment: Followed the answer: https://superuser.com/a/371912/310952, did the trick.